# How to Print the Head (First 10 Rows) and Tail (Last 10 Rows) of a Dataset in Python

Tags: python, class, dataset, categories

In Python (Jupyter Notebook) I have a dataset which has 5 columns that I have split into train and test data sets. I have to list the head (first 10 rows) and tail (last 10 rows) of the dataset. I am not allowed to use NumPy, Pandas, SciPy, and SciKit-Learn. I have to list the formatted data as follows (column1, column2 and column3 are integers and column4 and column5 are floats):

```
column1  column 2  column3    column4   column5     
1         0         5.0        male      200.4578  
0         1         24.67      female    300.06    
1         0         0.2        female    120.43
```

This is the code used to get the train and test datasets:

```
random.seed(900001)

n = len(data['coumn1'])
train_flag = [random.random() < 2/3 for i in range(n)]

train = defaultdict(list)
test  = defaultdict(list)

for i, flag in enumerate(train_flag):
    if flag:
        train['column1'].append(data['column1'][i])
        train['column2'].append(data['column2'][i])
        train['column3'].append(data['column3'][i])
        train['column4'].append(data['column4'][i])
        train['column5'].append(data['column5'][i])

    else:
        test['column1'].append(data['column1'][i])
        test['column2'].append(data['column2'][i])
        test['column3'].append(data['column3'][i])
        test['column4'].append(data['column4'][i])
        test['column5'].append(data['column5'][i])
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advanced

Comment: can you use any external library? can you provide the code you have and any attempt you've made?

Comment: If you have a list of rows, `data[:10]` will give the first 10 rows and `data[-10:]` will give you the last 10. What format is your data in?

Comment: I think I can use anything except NumPy, Pandas, SciPy, and SciKit-Learn. I am stuck on this so I haven't tried it, so sorry.

Comment: Thank you @ FamousJameous. I gave that a try and I got the following error: 




---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-45-141bd363d83f> in <module>()
----> 1 train[:10]

TypeError: unhashable type: 'slice'

Comment: The format is csv

Comment: I have included the code used to split the dataset into train and test in the original post :)